# Accurate IP detection regex help

Tags: .net, regex

I need to find Internal IP addresses by using a regex, I've managed to do it, but in the following cases all 4 is matching. I need a regex which doesn't match the first but matches the following 3. Each line is a different input.

```
! "version 10.2.0.4.0 detected"
+ "version 10.2.0.42 detected"
+ "version 10.2.0.4 detected"
+ "version 10.2.0.4"
```

edit: my current regex is

```
(?-i)\b10\.2.(?:[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @wrikken's answer was correct but it was in the comments of one of the deleted posts:

Here it is:

```
(?<![0-9]\.)((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?!\.[0-9])
```

Answer (score 2):

In PCRE:

```
/\b((1?[1-9]?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))(\.((1?[1-9]?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))){3}\b/
```

This is a rather strict match, not allowing multiple zeros, so 00.00.00.00 is invalid (0.0.0.0 is).

Comment: +1 for a  more complete answer -- it should work in .net (as required by the question) if you remove the leading and trailing slashes.

Comment: Well the slashes are part of PCRE, I always use PCRE when showing Regex.

Comment: @polemon: Yes, but the question explicitly states .NET is the engine he is using.

Comment: @bdukes: no it won't, the `\b` takes care of that.

Comment: Sorry, my comments was incorrect, this doesn't help. The correct answer was from Wrikken's comment. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The `\b` matches the "." after 10.2.0.4 (in .NET, if not other engines...)

Answer (score 0):

Use whichever regex that you want to match the IP (either of the above two work for your scenarios), and use `(?:^|\s+)` at the beginning and `(?:\s+|$)` at the end to make sure that there's whitespace or nothing around the value.

- `(?:)` defines a group that doesn't capture its contents
- `^` is the beginning of a line/string and `$` is the end of a line\string
- `\s+` is one or more whitespace characters
- `|` is the alternation operator, i.e. one or the other option on either side of the `|`

Using your expression as a starting point, you end up with

```
(?-i)(?:^|\s+)10\.2.(?:[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\s+|$)
```

Comment: Don't forget the quote for the last one.

Comment: I was assuming that was denoting the end of the string, rather than a literal quote...

Comment: thanks, but what i need was "(?!\.[0-9])" at the end before "\b"